# PHP, MYSQL Insert quantities of product ordered per office

Tags: php, mysqli

i would like to ask for help on how to save the quantities of each product ordered by each office. I would like also to save the total quantities of each products that was ordered and the total amounts.
 So far the only working in this are the auto computes and the query of products and offices.
And after that, the next output would echo all the products except for those products that no one has ordered.
Sorry about that :P

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGUQH.png)

[My output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzANf.png)

Here's my code so far

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project Procurement Management Plan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href='assets/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >

<script src="assets/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="assets/jquery/pr_table.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "ppmp.php" method="POST">
    <table border='2px' id='table' class='table' style="width:2800px">
        <thead>


            <tr>

                <th width="20"><div class="vertical">PREFIX</th>
                <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Stock #</th>
                <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Unit of Measure</th>
                <th width="400">Item Description</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th width="50px">UNIT <br>PRICE <br>Current Price</th>
                <th width="50px">UNIT PRICE X 1.10%<br>(Current Price x 1.10%)</th>
                <th></th>
                <th width="50px">Total No. of Users<br>(Office/s)</th>
                <?php
                $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
                    mysqli_select_db($connection,'thesis');

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM office_tbl"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);



                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
                        echo "<th class='vertical'><div class='vertical'>".$row['office_abb']."<br>".$row['office_id']."</th>";

                    }



                    mysqli_close($connection);
            ?>

                <th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th>           
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='6'></td>
                <td colspan='2'><strong>Total Employees

                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:63' value='0' id='input' class='total_qty' name='total_employees'></input></td>

                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input1' name='input1'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input2' name='input2'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input3' name='input3'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input4' name='input4'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input5' name='input5'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input6' name='input6'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input7' name='input7'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input8' name='input8'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input9' name='input9'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input10' name='input10'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input11' name='input11'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input12' name='input12'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input13' name='input13'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input14' name='input14'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input15' name='input15'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input16' name='input16'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input17' name='input17'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input18' name='input18'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input19' name='input19'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:50' value='0' id='input' class='input20' name='input20'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input21' name='input21'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input22' name='input22'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input23' name='input23'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input24' name='input24'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input25' name='input25'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input26' name='input26'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input27' name='input27'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input28' name='input28'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input29' name='input29'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input30' name='input30'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input31' name='input31'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input32' name='input32'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input33' name='input33'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input34' name='input34'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input35' name='input35'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input36' name='input36'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input37' name='input37'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input38' name='input38'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input39' name='input39'></input></td>
                <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input40' name='input40'></input></td>


            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan='4' align="center"><h2>01 - OFFICE SUPPLIES</strong>
                <td colspan= '3'></td>
                <td colspan='1'><strong>TOTAL QTY</td>
                <td colspan='40'></td>
            </tr>


            <?php
                $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
                    mysqli_select_db($connection,'thesis');

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM pro_tbl WHERE prefix = '1'"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

                    $index = 0;

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  

                        echo "<tr id='tr'>
                            <td>". $row['prefix'] . 
                            "<td>". $row['Stock_Num'] . 
                            "</td></input><td>". $row['UOM'] . 
                            "</td><td>" . $row['Description'] . 
                            "</td><td type='text' name='price1'></td><td>". $row['UP_CP'] . 
                            "</td><td><input class='unit_price' value=".$row['UP_Percentage']."></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='total_qty' name='input1'></input></td>
                            <td><span class ='total_qty' id='total_qty'></span></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input1' name='input1'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input2' name='input2'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input3' name='input3'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input4' name='input4'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input5' name='input5'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input6' name='input6'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input7' name='input7'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input8' name='input8'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input9' name='input9'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input10' name='input10'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input11' name='input11'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input12' name='input12'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input13' name='input13'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input14' name='input14'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input15' name='input15'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input16' name='input16'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input17' name='input17'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input18' name='input18'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input19' name='input19'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:50' value='0' id='input' class='input20' name='input20'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input21' name='input21'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input22' name='input22'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input23' name='input23'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input24' name='input24'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input25' name='input25'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input26' name='input26'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input27' name='input27'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input28' name='input28'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input29' name='input29'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input30' name='input30'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input31' name='input31'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input32' name='input32'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input33' name='input33'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input34' name='input34'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input35' name='input35'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input36' name='input36'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input37' name='input37'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input38' name='input38'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input39' name='input39'></input></td>
                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:40' value='0' id='input' class='input40' name='input40'></input></td>
                            <td>". $row['id'] ."</td>




                            <td style='width:40'><input type='text' style='width:140' value='0' id='input' class='total_amount' name='total_amount'></input></td>
                            </tr>"; 
                            $index++;
                    }



                    mysqli_close($connection);
            ?>

        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan ='2'><input value='Print' style='width:75' type="button" onclick="window.print()" />
                <td colspan ='1'><input value='Save' name='Save' style='width:75' type='submit'/>
                <td colspan ='1'><input name = "ppmp_no"></input>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<script>
    (function() {
"use strict";

$("table").on("keyup", "input", function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var input1 = parseFloat(row.find(".total_qty").val());
  var input2 = parseFloat(row.find(".unit_price").val());

  var total = input1 * input2;


  row.find(".total_amount").val(isNaN(total) ? "" : total.toFixed(2));
});

    })();
 </script>
```

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not links or as images. It makes it harder to troubleshoot, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to SO; Next time, please let us know what you have tried and what is not working etc. (i.e. exactly where you are stuck, with the inclusion of your code)

That said, instead of writing the code for you, let me show you the approach...

### Saving the Form Data

Without more information on this, I will attempt an answer with some assumptions--

1. Create a database

> **How to create a database:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php

2. Create a table to store quantity information (of course, you will have other tables; so create as needed, or do that later) in that database with ALL FIELDS that need to be stored, along with the quantity---assuming "Stock #" is a unique number per product, at the very least, you will need `stock_number` and `quantity` fields for the table

> **How to create a table & querying for information, etc.:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

3. Assuming you have a "Submit" or "OK" (etc... so long as there exist a button that posts to SELF/Another page for processing), here's how you would save the data:

   3.1 On the page resulting from the push of the button, you will first need
   to sanitize/validate the data (so that quantity is numerical and not alpha-
   num etc., for example)

   3.2 Then, you will need to insert the values in the table you created using
   the `INSERT` statement

   3.3 (Optional/but recommended as a good practice) Give an on-screen
   notification to the user that the entry is saved (or present with errors, if
   there are any)

> *Here's a good example of Step 3 from start to finish*: [http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/%7Ehankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html)

### Displaying the Saved Data

1. Navigate to the `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php` link and see how you can get the information from the table you created in Step 2, above.
2. Loop through the results

> *mysql_fetch_assoc*: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
> *mysql_fetch_array*: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

### Other recommendation(s)

In the event you are not familiar with a normalized database then the following are just a couple of starting points... Google for more:

> **An Introduction to Database Normalization:** http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html
>
> **Database normalization:** http://rdowla.cidamon.com/Book/MySQL/normalization.php
>
> **MySQL Database Normalization (Youtube Video):** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbjS7iujCbI

Hope this helps!